# Drive does not do “selftest” when using “smartctl?”

Tags: unix, freebsd, smart

I have one drive which does not want to do the selftest:

```
# smartctl -t long /dev/ada3
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE-p3 amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF OFFLINE IMMEDIATE AND SELF-TEST SECTION ===
Sending command: "Execute SMART Extended self-test routine immediately in off-line mode".
Drive command "Execute SMART Extended self-test routine immediately in off-line mode" successful.
Testing has begun.
Please wait 379 minutes for test to complete.
Test will complete after Thu Apr  2 07:25:59 2015

Use smartctl -X to abort test.
#
```

Now I would expect to see a message “routine in progress” in the status. Not only would I expect this but this is also how it works for all other devices!

However, instead I get “Aborted by host”:

```
# smartctl -l selftest /dev/ada3
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE-p3 amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%      1068         -
# 2  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%       761         -
```

On the other hand, if I re-run `smartctl -t long` I get the message that one check is already in progress and I should wait. I can successfully cancel it with `-X` and restart it with `-t long` and I get another line in the output with “Aborted by host.”

What’s going on here?

Note that even if the test may be actually performed (although the "90% remaining" is always stuck!) I need the message output "routine in progress" because I start smartctl from a script and I need to wait for the operation to be finished...

Comment: Drives typically offer three selftests. You only mention the "long" test.  What about the quick and short?

Comment: Good catch! It seems that the test just does not appear in "-l selftest" while running. First, another "Aborted by user" line is added only after I execute "smartctl -X" (cancel). Second, for "-t short" the test does not show up in "-l selftest" while running either! However, after it is completed I see the selftest with "Short offline   Completed without error". In any case, this is problematic because it breaks my script (I need to know when test self test is running)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your script wants to see if the test is done, you shouldn't be looking at the log, but rather at the self-test execution status ( in the output of `smartctl -a` ).